# Multiple quotients of Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I often see if written that 
$$(R/M)/N = R/(M,N)$$
in reference to rings and modules (especially polynomial rings). I can see that it's probably related to the Isomorphism Theorems but I can find a rigorous proof that this holds in general.

Note, R is a ring and M,N are ideals.

A concrete example would be that $(\mathbb{R}[X]/(X))/(2) = \mathbb{R}[X]/(2,X)$

Answer (score 2):

Note that as stated, it technically doesn't make sense, as $N$ isn't an ideal of $R/M$. The correct formulation is $(R/M)/(N/M)\cong R/(M,N)$. This is more or less exactly the third isomorphism theorem.

Note that using this for exactly things like
$$
(\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X))/(2) = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X)
$$
(i.e. modding out by one generator at a time, or changing the order of modding) is very common, but the $2$'s on either side are elements of different rings.

Answer (score 1):

This is partly obscured by practical notation. If $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal:

- If $r \in R$, we often use $r$ to denote the element $r + I \in R/I$
- If $J$ is an ideal of $R$, we often use $J$ to denote the ideal $(I+J)/I$ of $R/I$

So, you have to interpret the notation based on the context. To make matters more clear, I will add an overline for these reinterpretations; i.e. $\overline{r} = r + I$ and $\overline{J} = (I+J)/I$.

One reason why this notation is practical to use is that a lot of computations in this notation give the same result whether you compute them in $R$ or in $R/I$. For example:

> **Lemma:** If $J$ is generated by a family of elements $\{ j_n \}$, then $\overline{J}$ is generated by $\{ \overline{j_n} \}$

A more precise formulation of the isomorphism you're looking at is

$$ (R/I) / \overline{J} \cong R / (I+J) $$

When you write out what $\overline{J}$ means, you'll see this is precisely one of the homomorphism theorems:

$$ (R/I) / ((I+J)/I) \cong R / (I+J) $$

Answer (score 0):

Note the quotient is not taken modulo $N$ (which is neither an ideal nor an $R$-submodule of $R/M$), but modulo the ideal generated by $N$ in $R/M$. Now this ideal is
$$N\cdot R/M=(N+M)/M,$$
so the quotient you mention is but
$$(R/M)\big/(N\cdot R/M)=(R/M)\big/(N+M)/M\simeq R/(N+M)$$
by the 3rd isomorphism theorem.